# Export usage error when doing example from sbt docs

Tags: scala, sbt

The [sbt tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html) shows this example.

```
$ mkdir hello
$ cd hello
$ echo 'object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }' > hw.scala
$ sbt
...
> run
...
Hi!
```

However, when I try it, I get this:

```
$ mkdir hello
$ cd hello
$ echo 'object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }' > hw.scala
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/coryklein/playground/hello/)
[error] export usage:
[error]   export <tasks>+   Executes tasks and displays the equivalent command lines.
[error]
[error] export
[error]
```

My sbt version

```
$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.6
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the output of `sh -x sbt`

```
+ '[' -f /Users/coryklein/.sbtconfig ']'
+ exec /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.6/libexec/sbt
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/coryklein/playground/hello/)
[error] export usage:
[error]   export <tasks>+   Executes tasks and displays the equivalent command lines.
[error]
[error] export
[error]
```

I installed `sbt` via `brew install sbt`.

```
$ ll `which sbt`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 coryklein  admin    28B Oct 14 16:03 /usr/local/bin/sbt -> ../Cellar/sbt/0.13.6/bin/sbt
```

I'm trying to look through the source code to figure out what the problem is, but it's difficult when a working `sbt` is required to build `sbt` from source. :(

Comment: Can you execute `sh -x sbt` and add the output to the question? It seems that the startup script may be broken.

Comment: I added the output. It looks like it is expecting `~/.sbtconfig` to exist, but it doesn't.

Comment: I tried creating an `~/.sbtconfig` file, but it didn't make any difference. Hmm.

Comment: Since this question isn't getting any attention, I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out exactly why it failed to work, but I resolved it by doing [the manual install](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html) like so:

```
brew remove sbt
wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.tgz
extract sbt-0.13.6.tgz
mv sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar ~/bin
echo 'SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"\n
java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"' > ~/bin/sbt
chmod u+x ~/bin/sbt
```